# CI Continuous Integration with AWS & Jenkins

Tags: deployment, visualstudiocode, jenkins, ci, amazon-aws

I found some examples how to implement CI with AWS ad Jenkins but none of these examples explains clearly what AWS does. As i understood Jenkins is the CI server that interacts between master branch code Github and local code childe/slave branch developer. What is AWS doing precisely in this case. I saw some other examples not with AWS that a build server is needed. Is this the same in the case of AWS or wat is the functionality in this case. Please bear with me I do not have an IT background. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins is the CI software that runs on some form of compute platform (PC, server, whatever - something with an OS, storage and a CPU with memory); AWS is being used to provide a virtual server on which Jenkins is installed and run.

Note that, certainly in our Salesforce CI implementation, all you actually need the "CI server" to do is execute a script that:

- Creates a scratch org.
- Pushes your metadata, from git, to the scratch org.
- Invokes Apex unit testing on the scratch org.
- Invokes JEST or other LWC unit testing.

The only element of this that actually takes significant CPU time on the CI server is the JEST or other LWC unit test execution - everything else is simply invocation of `sfdx` commands that actually cause most of the work to be performed on your Salesforce instance/org.

NB: We actually use Docker and Bitbucket pipelines to realize our CI functionality so I cannot provide specific details of how to use Jenkins and AWS in this context.